# Could be better or...? Usage of a perfect infinitive

Tags: perfect-constructions

The essay is not bad, but *could be better* or *could have been better*? The essay was written a few days ago, but is being discussed and edited right now. Which form is correct?

Comment: Both are fine.  Why do you think that one is "correct" and the other is not?

Comment: It depends. Is there a possibility of rewriting/improving the essay after the critique?

Comment: @ user3169: No.

Comment: I seem to be mixing the present and the past... "Could be better" is just a statement of the fact and a real possibility of improving - now, "could have been better" means that the student could have done it better but he didn't and the opportunity to improve the essay was missed. Am I right?